# Meaning of suffix '-sex' in 'Sussex, Middlesex'

Tags: names, geography

I know that Sussex and Middlesex are in England. It looks to me as if there is a pattern in names.

What does the suffix -sex mean? Where does it come from?

Comment: http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=Middlesex

Comment: Why is this closed as off-topic? It seems like a perfectly good question to me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The -sex suffix is from Anglo-Saxon / Old English, with the actual meaning being "Saxon".

- Sussex is essentially "South Saxon".
- Middlesex is "Middle Saxon".
- Essex is "East Saxon".
- Wessex is "West Saxon".​​​​​​​

Most of the wiki pages for these places will have the toponymy definition.

Comment: There seems to be one missing...  Is there a.. hmm.. "Nosex"?  ;)

Comment: @Izkata The *Seaxe* settled on the south coast, not in the north. However, there are county names on the east coast (in East Anglia, settled by Angles) which distinguish north and south populations: Norfolk and Suffolk.

Comment: @StoneyB Unless "Saxon" means "coast" (does it?), I don't see how that's relevant to my joke/comment...

Comment: @Izkata: Because of the shape of England, the Saxon area had a south, centre, east and west, but no specific north; the closest equivalent was called *East Anglia* due to the close connection between Angles and Saxons.

Comment: @TimLymington, that doesn’t really make sense. Even if the Saxons were spread out in an entirely V-shaped area, the ones at the top of the ‘fingers’ of the V would still be the northernmost Saxons. _Any_ geographical distribution will always have a bit that can be considered ‘north’. It’s just that the Saxons didn’t utilise that possibility when place-naming.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet    It seems more likely that this is how they were referred to by the non-Saxon northeners, in which case all the Saxons were southerners to them, but they distinguished between the east/west/far south Saxons.

Comment: @Mynamite, good point!

Comment: @Izkata The northern Saxons must have been married.

Answer (score 2):

The suffix originates from the word Saxon, which is derived from the German state of Saxony

Comment: Surely the other way round. Saxony is derived in the same way as Essex etc from the Saxon tribe

Comment: Yes, the name of the German state of Saxony derives from the name of the Germanic tribe of the Saxons.  It was a confederation of Angles and Saxons who settled in Britain and incidentally helped create the basis for English. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Saxony