# Meaning and etymology of Middlesex

Tags: meaning, etymology, old-english

What is the meaning of Middlesex? I read somewhere that ***seax*** is an old English word meaning a type of Germanic knife, so was the county's original name Middleseax?

I'm looking for the etymology of the word 'Middlesex'.

Comment: [*Middlesex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middlesex_(disambiguation)) is a place name that you can easily Google (unless there's some slang meaning of it that I don't know, in which case you need to put the usage in your question). We discourage people from asking answers that are easily found on the web, as that wastes our time.

Comment: @PeterShor Yeah, how dare they, when we have such important work to do.

Comment: @PeterShor As per Deadrat's answer, there's more to the question than meets the eye, it seems.

Comment: @Araucaria In that case, context is required in the question.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122887/meaning-of-suffix-sex-in-sussex-middlesex

Comment: Already previously asked & closed as off-topic in the question referenced by Ste.

Comment: I think you should roll back your edit to capitalize the word, Rathony, until we know whether this is really a reference to a proper name.

Comment: @Rathony I think it's fair to call it a duplicate unless the OP tells us that there's a context other than the name of a county in England, say a new slang word for hermaphrodite. Or the rest period between two acts of intercourse.  Or something.

Comment: @Rathony I was careless in looking at the edit history.  You just edited the header, right?  It looks like Araucaria edited the body.  Sorry about that.  Cyndi has had time to advise us that the question isn't close-worthy, and she hasn't, so it will be gone soon.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to tell without any context, but if you mean *Middlesex*, with an initial capital letter, then it's a place name, the original one in England.  The *-sex* part is a reference to a group of people called the Saxons, a Germanic tribe that came to England after the Romans left.  Apparently some settled in the east (so that location came to be called Essex); some settled in the west (so that location came to be called Wessex).  And some settled in between, so their place was called Middlesex. Check [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Middlesex).

Comment: And some settled in the south, Sussex.

Comment: 'Middlesex' is also used as the name of a novel by Jeffery Eugenides. The main character is intersex, so I think it is used as a more euphonious synonym in that instance rather than in reference to the county. But I've never been sureoif the author's intent with that.